# How can I use two lists as arguments in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am learning python and I came up with this exercise, but I can't find a way that this can work. The idea is to loop through two lists and use each value as an argument to the function.

```
def make_tshirt(size, text='I love Python!'):
    v = []
    if len(text) <= 20:
        v = ['S', 'M', 'L']
    elif len(text) <= 30:
        v = ['M', 'L']
    elif len(text) <= 50:
        v = ['L']
    else:
        v = []

    if text == '':
        text = 'I love Python!'

    if size in v:
        print(f"You ordered a {size} tshirt with the text '{text}'.")
    else:
        print("The size you want don't have enough space to your text.")

sizes = ['m', 's', 'l', 's']
texts = ['I like Python', 'Am I a robot?', 'Weird Year', 'God, Our savior']

make_tshirt([x.upper() for x in sizes], [y for y in texts])
```

I need this code to print the result of the funciton four times, as shown below:

```
You ordered a M tshirt with the text 'I like Python'.    
You ordered a S tshirt with the text 'Am I a robot?'.    
You ordered a L tshirt with the text 'Weird Year'.    
You ordered a S tshirt with the text 'God, Our savior'.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can use `zip()` function which takes two or more iterables as arguments of function and returns an iterator of the tuples. The nth tuple will contain the nth element from each of input iterables. Here is the demonstration:

```
def make_tshirt(size, text='I love Python!'):
    v = []
    if len(text) <= 20:
        v = ['S', 'M', 'L']
    elif len(text) <= 30:
        v = ['M', 'L']
    elif len(text) <= 50:
        v = ['L']
    else:
        v = []

    if text == '':
        text = 'I love Python!'

    if size in v:
        print(f"You ordered a {size} tshirt with the text '{text}'.")
    else:
        print("The size you want don't have enough space to your text.")

sizes = ['m', 's', 'l', 's']
texts = ['I like Python', 'Am I a robot?', 'Weird Year', 'God, Our savior']

for size, text in zip([x.upper() for x in sizes], texts):
    make_tshirt(size, text)
```

Comment: Good solution but in the spirit of iterators, I think I'd change `[x.upper() for x in sizes]` to `(x.upper() for x in sizes)`. The first preallocates the list, the second iterates values as zip is iterated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `zip` built-in function to get each order's size and text.

```
for pair in zip(sizes, texts):
    make_tshirt(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Comment: Side note: string comparison is case-sensitive, so just changing the function call with the code above won't yield the intended result. Changing all elements of `sizes` to uppercase will solve this.